# Disable Right to Left editing in VSCode in mixed language files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a JSON file that I'm copying Arabic Language strings into. These have been translated, and I do not speak Arabic.

The Right-To-Left language support is driving me insane. I want to just use my right and left arrow keys to edit these strings and highlight, but the mixed language in the CSS file causes the cursor to jump and act unpredictably when trying to edit the arabic string.

Please tell me there is a setting I can disable right-to-left language support and exclusively use left-to-right cursor movement, even when VS code detects an arabic string.

Searching the settings / Searching online everywhere

Press the right arrow key to move the cursor to the right within an arabic string instead of insanely moving it to the left, and then when you read the quote, going back to right, so that it is impossible to use or edit these strings.

Comment: this is still a frustrating issue with vs-code, I think at-least they should keep it as it is as sublime does it to not do any black magic on it

Comment: This is especially frustrating when you have a string literal inside some code and you don't want the editor to behave like this. I just want to cut and paste the entire string. I don't want to edit it!!! I hope Microsoft fixes this. I completely understand it if you are editing strings and you are a native speaker but if you are not and do not wish to do this, this is very frustrating.